# Magento2.3: Product detail page is not working

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, product-detail-page

I have tried installing the social share extension but getting the below error when I try to open the product detail page.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element
>   'referenceBlock', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed.
>   Line: 1778

How can I resolve this?

Comment: your xml file of module has 'as' attribute, which not allowed.

Comment: Which social share extension did you install? It's likely there's some code in the module's `view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file with `<referenceBlock as="">` which is invalid XML or your product has it set in it's custom layout xml in the admin.